# ext3 code understanding

Tags: c, struct, filesystems, linux-kernel

```
struct inode_operations ext3_dir_inode_operations = {
        .create         = ext3_create,
        .lookup         = ext3_lookup,
}
```

This struct is assign to inode structure and further to file system operation structure.
My question is what is this flag `.create`? Do we do the assignment in the structure itself?
Or is it some other version of C (C99, C89?) that allows this kind of operation?

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a C99 designated initialiser.  It's equivalent to, in C89:

```
struct inode_operations ext3_dir_inode_operations = { 0 };
ext3_dir_inode_operations.create = ext3_create;
ext3_dir_inode_operations.lookup = ext3_lookup;
```

Answer (score 2):

`create` and `lookup` is element of `struct inode_operations`.  `.create=ext3_create` means `ext3_dir_inode_operations.create=ext3_create` and so on for other elements of the struct.  Not sure from which standard this came into being.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [struct inode_operations](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.34/include/linux/fs.h#L1514)